# setDefaultButton on JPanel in Applet

Tags: java, null, applet, defaultbutton

```
public class test_Applet extends Applet {
    public void init(){
        JPanel test = new testPanel();
        test.setVisible(true); 
        this.add(test);
        System.out.println(test.getRootPane());
        //returns null
    }

}
```

I need a way to change the DefaultButton on my JPanel, so that when someone pressed enter a button in the JPanel is pressed. However, I can't do that since getRootPane() returns null.

Comment: public testPanel() {
            initComponents();
            this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
            //throws a nullPointerException
        
        }

Comment: You want to extend [JApplet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html), not Applet.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Also note the advice of @VGR - I don't think there is any way to set a default button in AWT.